# Understanding why the inverse looks like this.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, condition-number

This a part from Carl D. Meyer book:

> [image]

But I do not understand why the denominator in (3.8.1) contains $d^{T}c$ and not $c d^{T}$, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Think already dimension-wise. $d^Tc$ is a scalar, $cd^T$ is a matrix of size $n\times n$, so doing $1 + cd^T$ does not even make sense!

Comment: [Sherman–Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman–Morrison_formula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $d^Tc$ is a scalar and $cd^T$ is a $n\times n$ matrix.
Using the textbook hint, multiply the matrix and its inverse to get $I$:

$(I+cd^T)(I - \dfrac{cd^T}{1+d^Tc}) =I+cd^T - \dfrac{cd^T+c(d^Tc)d^T}{1+d^Tc} =  I+cd^T - \dfrac{cd^T(1+d^Tc)}{1+d^Tc}=I $

Answer (score 1):

[Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) reads
$$
\left(I + UV \right)^{-1} = I - U \left(I + VU \right)^{-1}V.
$$
With $U = c$ and $V = d^T$, you get your answer. In particular
$$
\left(I + VU \right)^{-1} = \frac1{1 + d^Tc}.
$$